# What are Applicative left and right star sequencing operators expected to do?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I looked up the implementation and it's even more mysterious:

```
-- | Sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument.
(*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
a1 *> a2 = (id <$ a1) <*> a2
-- This is essentially the same as liftA2 (flip const), but if the
-- Functor instance has an optimized (<$), it may be better to use
-- that instead. Before liftA2 became a method, this definition
-- was strictly better, but now it depends on the functor. For a
-- functor supporting a sharing-enhancing (<$), this definition
-- may reduce allocation by preventing a1 from ever being fully
-- realized. In an implementation with a boring (<$) but an optimizing
-- liftA2, it would likely be better to define (*>) using liftA2.

-- | Sequence actions, discarding the value of the second argument.
(<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
(<*) = liftA2 const
```

I don't even understand why does `<$` deserve a place in a typeclass. It looks like there is some sharing-enhancig effect which `fmap . const` might not have and that `a1` might not be "fully realized". How is that related to the meaning of `Applicative` sequencing operators?

Comment: `liftA2 (flip const) fa fb` = `fmap (\a b->b) fa <*> fb` = `fmap (const id) fa <*> fb` = `const id <$> fa <*> fb` (= `id <$ fa <*> fb`). that's the meaning. lists are easy enough to handle, try `(,) <$> [1,2] <*> [10,20,30]`, `const id <$> [1,2] <*> [10,20,30]`, `[1,2] *> [10,20,30]` and `[1,2] <* [10,20,30]`.

Comment: and `fa <* fb` = `liftA2 const fa fb` = `fmap const fa <*> fb` = `(\a b -> a) <$> fa <*> fb`. compare it with when `(,)` = `\a b -> (a,b)` is used, as above.

Answer (score 7):

These operators sequence two applicative actions and provide the result of the action that the arrow points to. For example,

```
> Just 1 *> Just 2
Just 2

> Just 1 <* Just 2
Just 1
```

Another example in writing parser combinators is

```
brackets p = char '(' *> p <* char ')'
```

which will be a parser that matches `p` contained in brackets and gives the result of parsing `p`.

In fact, `(*>)` is the same as `(>>)` but only requires an `Applicative` constraint instead of a `Monad` constraint.

> I don't even understand why does `<$` deserve a place in a typeclass.

The answer is given by [the Functor documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-): `(<$)` can sometimes have more efficient implementations than its default, which is `fmap . const`.

> How is that related to the meaning of Applicative sequencing operators?

In cases where `(<$)` is more efficient, you want to maintain that efficiency in the definition of `(*>)`.

Comment: Indeed, some care in writing `fmap` is required for recursive types to allow it to inline into the default `<$` and avoid a bunch of worthless `const a b` thunks.

Comment: `Data.Sequence.Seq` is a good example of a type with a peculiarly efficient `<$`. `<$` for that type takes time and space logarithmic in the length of the sequence, while `fmap` takes linear time and space.